# Harmonic function

Tags: harmonic-functions

Let $B(0;1)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^N;|x|≤1\}$, the ball of $\mathbb{R}^N$ equipped with the euclidian scalar product 
$$x⋅y=x_1y_1+...+x_Ny_N,\ \ \ x=(x_1,...,x_N),\ \ \ y=(y_1,...,y_N)\ \ \ |x|=\sqrt{x \cdot x}$$
Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ two real numbers, $\alpha \geq0$ , $a \in \partial B(0,1)$ fix. 
$$h(x)=\log\left((1−x\cdot a)^{\alpha}+|x−a|^{\beta}\right)$$
Can we find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $h$ is harmonic in $B(0,1)$?

( harmonic signifies $\Delta_{x}h(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^N \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x_i^2}$ ).

Comment: What ought to happen is for this copy to be migrated to M.SE, and then closed there as duplicate.  I worry, though, that the software is set up so that once that copy is closed, this copy bounces back here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a duplicate of a question on math.stackexchange.